# Add Neutral Button in DialogFragment which implements DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

As you can see in the code below I have tried to add a neutral button which sets the `query_date` and dismisses the dialog. Unfortunately this below does not work: the neutral button is not displayed at all.

I want to have a middle button called "today" and does that action.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setNeutralButton("Today", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    query_date = now_date;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis() );
            return dialog;
        }

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
            SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");                
            sdfSource.setTimeZone(tz);
            Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day).getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE', 'd LLL");

            query_date = sdfSource.format(date);
            change_date_button.setText(sdfDestination.format(date));

            load_more_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new get_events().execute();
        }

    }
```

The way I call the DialogFragment from a onClick button listener is below:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Is it possible to have a neutral button in a `DatePickerDialog` Fragment? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating two Dialogs. One AlertDialog and another DatePickerDialog. You should use only one:

```
@Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

 DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
 dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis() );
 dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Today", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         query_date = now_date;
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 });
 return dialog;
```

}

Comment: This solution does not seem to work in every device. I have an Huawei MediaPad T3 with Android 7.0 and I can not see the neutral button. In other devices the button works fine. I suppose that the workaround is to use onShowListener and findViewById in order to use neutral button. (I have not tried it though)